# Converting LINQ statement from query to fluent c# syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hey, I'm stuck in a converting a simple Linq statement from query syntax to fluent syntax in C#. I think that is possible, but I need a hint.

```
from property in target.GetType().GetProperties()
select new
{
   Name = property.Name,
   Value = property.GetValue(target, null)
};
```

to..

```
var props = target.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p=>p.Name.... )
```

What I need change after `Select`?

Comment: What are you asking exactly ?

Comment: the `....` is my question. Sorry about the unclean question. My edit correct this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var props = target
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => new { 
        Name = p.Name, 
        Value = p.GetValue(target, null)
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, As ReSharper suggests I just change to: `origin.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => new {p.Name, Value = p.GetValue(origin, null)});` Name = p.Name is unnecessary.

Comment: It is indeed unnecessary in this case, but it was in the other syntax as well. :) I thought perhaps you had a coding style which required it, e.g. to have a consistent look with the line below.

Answer (score 1):

```
var props = target.GetType()
                  .GetProperties()
                  .Select(p => new {
                      Name = p.Name,
                      Value = p.GetValue(target, null)
                  });
```

?